# Can I hide tab bar in gnome-terminal even when I use multiple tab?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am asking this, because I can't seems to find question regarding this.
I love gnome-terminal, because I can copy paste from/to this terminal window, and because I already set it up to use bitmap font (non anti alias), so it has the same appearance as xterm.

But in my preference, one thing missing : how can I always disable/hide tab bar when I open multiple tab? I didn't like this tab element gui. But I don't think there is a trivial option to do it.. or, is it?

Comment: You mean you don't want tabs all-together or you don't want to see the tab GUI?

Comment: Thanks for replying (it's been a while..), all-together. But, actually now I am using KDE Konsole instead of Gnome-Terminal. The reason is because I can completely hide the tab, and easily switch to other tab using SHIFT+arrow. I still don't know how to hide the tab in gnome-terminal though ;)

Comment: Another one that allows this option is guake, `sudo apt-get install guake`. Additionally, guake is a "drop-down" terminal that hides with a user set hot-key so it is very convenient.

Comment: hm, thank you for this. A years ago thread, and now I am working in OSX. Because of this, I am trying this for another console flavour :) https://github.com/Swordfish90/cool-retro-term